# Flex + Topology View

Tags: apache-flex, topology

Currently I'm working on creating a view of displaying a entire school database in the form of a graphical view.

1. School;
2. Classes;
3. Teachers; and
4. Students

I display an Image for each of the above mentioned ones. I need a plugin/tool (freeware) to use to create the links between them.

My default view would be a School Image, either on click of Image / Zoom-In (Zoom-out) I want to display Classes.

When I select a click by clicking it or mouse over a particular class and zoom-in, I want to display the teachers and students.

Could some-one suggest me a tool that would help me do the same.

**P.S.** I've tried SpringGraph, but it lacks on a lot of features.

Comment: Would a tree with custom icons on each level do what you need it to? Doing that is pretty easy.

Comment: Sounds interesting, can you please share some more info on this?

Answer (score 1):

I would check out [Flare](http://flare.prefuse.org/).  Check out the [demo](http://flare.prefuse.org/demo).  I think you will be most interested in the Layouts section.

Comment: Seems like a nice one, so let me start experimenting this right away.

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be the [RaVis](http://code.google.com/p/birdeye/wiki/RaVis) portion of the BirdEye project.  The graphs it generates are pretty customizable (i.e. controlling the image used for each node), as seen in [this demo](http://birdeye.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ravis/RaVisExamples/example-binaries/RaVisExplorer.html#).  The default interactivity (double-click to navigate, information on mouse-over) is solid as well.

Comment: I've tried RaVis, but not much help. Thanks for the tip though

Answer (score 0):

Check the "tour de flex" 
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/tourdeflex/

It's a big demo of what you can do with flex. Check the Data Visualisation part, it's contains some very nice exemple

But i doubs that you will find exactly what your are looking for, why not just code it.

- A image for the scool.
- a list of image for classes.
- a list of teacher and student images for each classes.
- OnClick + transition event

No ?

Comment: Unfortunately I am learning Flex on the go and have no helping hands expect for you experts around :)